# By how much does the temperature of a cool Cola can increase by condensation of the ambient moisture on its surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, everyday-life, estimation, condensation

Assuming standard ambient temperature and pressure, how can we estimate the increase in the temperature of a typical, cool beverage can produced by the condensation of ambient moisture on its surface? I'd like to know if this increase is large enough to be noticed.

Comment: Do you have some initial ideas on the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rough estimate: we can approximate the shape of the can with a cylinder of radius $R=3,2$ cm and height $h=15,5$ cm (those are the dimensions of a Cola can). Its total area can be found by using

$$A_T=A_L+2A_B= 2\pi R h + 2\pi R^2$$

which gives us $A_T$=$375,8$ cm$^2$. Assuming that water vapor condensation forms a 1 mm thick, continuous sheet of water over the can's surface, and using water's density ($\rho=1$ kg/m$^3$), we can compute the mass of the condensed water as follows:

$$m=\rho V = \rho A_T \epsilon$$

where $\epsilon$ is the thickness of the sheet. I'm getting $m\approx3,758 \times10^{-5}$ kg. The amount of energy released by the condensation of this quantity of water is given by the relation

$$Q=mL_{water}$$

where $L_{water}$ is the [specific latent heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat#Latent_heat_for_condensation_of_water)  for condensation of water, which is $2264.76$ kJ/kg. Then, $Q\approx85,12$ J. In a $330$ mL can, and assuming that the beverage density is close to water's, there's $0,33$ kg of beverage. The ratio of the amount of heat energy transferred to an object and the resulting increase in temperature of the object is its [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity):

$$Q=c_p \Delta T$$

which we can also assume close to water's: $c_p=$ $4185$ J/(kg⋅K). Then, the resulting increase in the temperature of our beverage is $\Delta T \approx 0,02$ K. Not a big deal, I'd say.